# Programmatically select value in DropDown element with JavaScript in Lightswitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, visual-studio-lightswitch, dropdownbox

I need to pre-select one of the options from a Drop-Down element ("Type" in picture) when my LSML form loads.

When the form loads I need to see that the value "2-intermediate-type" was already selected in this element.

This is a form that adds a new entity to database.

The solution I tried was to write some JavaScript code in `postRender` event of this Drop-Down element.

Like this:

```
myapp.AddBeneficiary.Beneficiary_TIP_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    $(contentItem).text("2-intermediate-type");
    element.textContent = "2-intermediate-type";
    $(element) = "2-intermediate-type";
    $(element).options["2-intermediate-type"].selected = true;
}
```

None of the above four variants worked for me.

I am a beginner with both MS Lightswitch and JavaScript, so I am not sure if this is a hard or easy task in this context.

But I'm however surprised that it doesn't work so easily because on other programming languages / platforms this task is trivial.

Comment: Have you tried `element.value = '2-intermediate-type';` ?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the architechture of Lightswitch and sharepoint.

By selecting an option, you are not really setting value or selected. Instead, you are changing text of .ui-btn-text. Here is what I have:

if (screen.Customers.selectedItem.countryDrop != null) {
            $("#filterRecentByCountry").parent().find(".ui-btn-text").find("span").text(screen.Customers.selectedItem.countryDrop);
}

I have custom dropdown list, so I use ID, but the principle is exactly the same with native dropdowns. I really hope this helps.

Comment: I have the same problem, please elaborate your answer a bit more: 
a) what is countryDrop? Is that the attribute from the Customers data object that relates to a Country data object?
b) I assume this $("#filterRecentByCountry").parent().find(".ui-btn-text").find("span") returns the drop down html object?

Answer (score 0):

One part of the solution is like @VadimsSamsinovs said: changing the text of the drop down does not help, we need to set the object to the data model object. This will automatically change the view.

1.) Create a query, that returns you the object you would like to have being selected, e.g. **GetBenificiaryTipDefault()**. During the query creation I set the query property "Number of results Returned" to "One", so it only returns one object.

2.) Call the query from JavaScript and apply the returned object to the drop down content item:

```
myapp.AddBeneficiary.Beneficiary_TIP_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.GetBenificiaryTipDefault().execute().then(function (response) {               
        contentItem.value = response.results[0];
    }); 
}
```

cheers